# How to set portrait and landscape view?

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

Hi i am developing one windows phone app, i need to set support portrait and landscape view does not any alignment issue.

I am using my code is given below

```
<Grid Height="113" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="3">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush  ImageSource="Images/footer_bg .png"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
            <Button BorderThickness="0"  Click="Home" Height="87">
                <Image Source="Images/home_30.png"  Stretch="Uniform"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="66" Width="68"  />
            </Button>
            <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="Home" Padding="30,0,0,0" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Arial"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Margin="60,0,224,0"  x:Name="reg"  Visibility="Visible">
            <Button BorderThickness="0"   Width="120"  Click="register" Height="87">
                <Image Source="Images/register_30.png"  Stretch="Uniform"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="66" Width="68"  />
            </Button>
            <TextBlock  Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  FontSize="20" FontFamily="Arial" Text="Register"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Margin="60,0,224,0" x:Name="regi" >
            <Button BorderThickness="0"  Click="account" Width="120"  Height="87" >
                <Image Source="Images/register_30.png"   Stretch="Uniform"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="66" Width="68"  />
            </Button>
            <TextBlock Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  FontSize="20" FontFamily="Arial" Text="Account" ></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56" Margin="180,20,50,0">
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="Images/social_48.png"  Stretch="Uniform" x:Name="imgShareOff"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  ManipulationStarted="imgShareOff_ManipulationStarted_1"   />
                <Image Source="Images/social_48.png"  Stretch="Uniform" x:Name="imgShareOn" VerticalAlignment="Top" ManipulationStarted="imgShareOn_ManipulationStarted_1"    />
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock Foreground="White" Margin="-42,10,-27,0" Padding="10,0,0,0" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Arial" Text="Social Share"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="485">
            <Button BorderThickness="0"  Margin="352,0,0,0"  Click="Contact" Height="87">
                <Image Source="Images/msg_30.png"  Stretch="Uniform"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="66" Width="68"  />
            </Button>
            <TextBlock Foreground="White" Margin="352,0,0,0" Padding="20,0,0,0" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Arial" Text="Contact Us"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

I got an result given below image.In the landscape View i need to get proper space on right and left.I have to get proper landscape view

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you considered using the App Bar control instead? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431813(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can put the menu elements in a Grid with 4 columns, each of them having a Width of "*". This way the menu spans the screen width.
Or put them in a StackPanel which has a HorizontalAlignment of "Center". This way the menu has a symmetric margin.

But instead of doing this, you should read best practices, design guidelines and similar stuff: the menu of a WP app id ALWAYS on the edge of the hardware buttons. It doesn't use gradients or even gray scales. If you don't follow these rules, your app will feel "wrong" to WP users and will be rated badly.